# Post emojis to Twitter with PHP

Tags: php, twitter, emoji

I have code to post to Twitter with PHP which works well using [this guide](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_twitter_with_php)

I am trying to attach Emojis to the posts, but have been unsuccessful so far.

I am wondering if anyone knows how, using the above guide, how I would go about being able to add emojis to each tweet generating the code via PHP.

Essentially I would need to put whatever code is needed into some kind of variable in PHP.

Comment: Does this help at all? http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Comment: Hi Mari M, thanks for your reply. I have the codes, etc... but I just don;t know how to put these into variables in PHP that will then render in the post to Twitter

Comment: Can you edit your post to include an attempt you've tried that hasn't worked out?

Comment: HI, I've spotted my mistake! I need to add utf8_bytes to the variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add **utf8_bytes** to the variable

Comment: I think a code example would be nice, if somebody else in the future has the same issue let this question be the reference.

Comment: The code is in the original code I used, I just need to put the utf8_bytes in front of the variable to post $emoji=utf8_bytes()